# Python: Indexing tuples to create new dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Is it possible to create new individual dictionaries based on unique 1st tuple values from a single dictionary, and map corresponding keys and values?

Working explanation:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

TestString = 'this dog, this dog. this, animal this animal animal this animal this dog that animal'

def get_dict(string):

    # Create list of individual words without punctuation
    x = re.findall(r"[\w']+", string)

    # Get sum of individual two-word shingles from list
    x = (Counter(zip(x,x[1:])))
    print x

get_dict(TestString)
```

Returns the following dict:

`Counter({('this', 'dog'): 3, ('this', 'animal'): 3, ('animal', 'this'): 3, ('dog', 'this'): 2, ('animal', 'animal'): 1, ('dog', 'that'): 1, ('that', 'animal'): 1})`

From this is it possible to create these individual dicts:

`this = {'dog': 3, 'animal': 3}
animal = {'this': 3, 'animal': 1}
dog = {'this': 2, 'that': 1}
that = {'animal': 1}`

Where the new dict names are the unique 1st elements of the tuples, and the keys and values map accordingly?

Comment: It's possible but you almost certainly don't want it... Why not a dictionary with unique keys of `this`/`animal` etc... whose values are then dictionaries?

Comment: It's a particular approach to structuring the data that I require for downstream analysis.

Comment: what if the words are not syntactically valid variable names or shadow builtins or are the same as keywords? :p

Comment: All valid points and your answer is great, but I can't work with a single dict, really sorry. Is there anyway round this?

Comment: At your own risk... at the end of the code - do `globals().update(counts)` - but when things go **horribly wrong**... and they **will go horribly wrong**... you probably won't garner sympathy from anyone :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129686/discussion-between-rdj-and-jon-clements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single dictionary whose keys are the first words, and whose values are a dictionary of the second word and frequency, eg:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

text = 'this dog, this dog. this, animal this animal animal this animal this dog that animal'
words = re.findall('\w+', TestString)
counts = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for word1, word2 in zip(words, words[1:]):
    counts[word1][word2] += 1
```

This'll give you `counts` as:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f0ca8565378>,
            {'animal': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'animal': 1, 'this': 3}),
             'dog': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'that': 1, 'this': 2}),
             'that': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'animal': 1}),
             'this': defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'animal': 3, 'dog': 3})})
```

Then something like `counts['this']['dog']` will return `3`... etc...